# Trying to line up Twitter, Pinterest & Facebook buttons

Tags: css, button, alignment, media

There are a couple other questions like this on Stack Overflow but I couldn't get anything out of them so have to post my own. Here's the URL...

http://quoteic.com/part?no=PC68EN302RC25

I'd like the 3 buttons to be on a single line and be bottom aligned. A good example of this is on Fiverr's site (sorry wouldn't let me post a screenshot).

Comment: What are the HTML markup and styles you have used currently? Can you please provide them in your question?

Comment: I'm just including the 3 code snippets from them on a single line, I've not tried to style them.

Answer (score 1):

Place all the buttons into their own DIVs and style them with a width and a `float:left`, then wrap all of this into a DIV. This helped me align and control their positions.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet, because they are all slightly different, and different again across different browsers is to wrap each one in your own code. e.g.

```
<div class="btn_facebook"></div>
<div class="btn_twitter"></div>
```

etc.

And wrap that in another container:

```
<div class="social_buttons"></div>
```

Then either float them left, or display inline block. Set each one to the same height and they will line up as best they can.

Unless you are willing to go through each browser nudging them about with relative positioning they will never line up perfectly. If you did want to do that though:

```
.social_buttons > div {
    position: relative;
}
```

and

```
.social_buttons .btn_facebook {
    top: -2px;
}
```

Or whatever shows the best results.

Make sure to set all the widths of each button to their minimum though, otherwise they are all hugely wide. Facebook especially.

Comment: I added the divs as you suggested thanks. Can I float them left right in the div or do I need to do it in the css file? Right now they are stacking on top of each other.

Comment: I tried style="float: left" in each of the inner <div> and it didn't work.

Comment: To align elements set to inline-block you just need to set the text-align on the parent element. Just make sure that parent element is wide enough to accommodate them all. Remember to set the widths of the buttons too. Facebook's default is 450 if it is not specifically set down to 90.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an unordered list and put each image within a list item and display inline.  This will then show your links in a horizontal line.  You can also find free to use social media icons (16px or 32px etc.) from sites so that way all your icons are a consistent size.

```
<div id="socialmedia">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="YourTwitterFileName" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.pinterest.com" target="_blank"><img src="YourPinterestFileName" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="YourFacebookFileName" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the style you could use for the ul

```
#socialmedia ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 5px;
}   

#socialmedia img {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Argg, check it out now. Still a no go.

Comment: Did you implement the styles into the CSS?

Comment: Right now the it's taking on a class called "product-details" which is using "display: block"

Comment: Yes, I put the styles in the css. I saw an example somewhere else that had the id in the <ul> tag so I changed that and took out the div, that's probably when you looked at it. I put the div back in just like you had sent it but it's still not working.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is to create the following structure:

```
<table id="social_links_tab">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="http://link_to_twitter_page"><img src="http://src_of_img"/></a></td>
        <td><a href="http://link_to_pinterest_page"><img src="http://src_of_img"/></a></td>
        <td><a href="http://link_to_facebook_page"><img src="http://src_of_img"/></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This would effectively line up the icons horizontally next to each other. Further, feel free to attach styles to the `<table>` or any of the specific elements inside.

Comment: Thanks Nagendra, I'm going to try the <div> first and then if that doesn't work maybe try the table. I had actually tried this earlier and it did get them all on one row but they still didn't line up correctly.